# Formatting a vector of numbers using format() in R

Tags: r, formatting, format

When I attempt to format a vector of numbers using format(), only the first number respects the "digits" argument

```
format(c(1.508390e-06, 8.487128e-02,  4.185008e-01,  4.785161e-01, -8.332557e-01),        
    digits = 3, scientific = FALSE)
[1] " 0.00000151" " 0.08487128" " 0.41850080" " 0.47851610" "-0.83325570"
```

However, if I sapply it to each element in turn, I get the expected result.

```
sapply(c(1.508390e-06, 8.487128e-02,  4.185008e-01,  4.785161e-01, -8.332557e-01), FUN = function(x) { format(x,digits = 3, scientific = FALSE) } )
[1] "0.00000151" "0.0849"     "0.419"      "0.479"      "-0.833"
```

Am I missing something here?

Note that if I set scientific = FALSE, then all numbers are formatted correctly:

```
format(c(1.508390e-06, 8.487128e-02,  4.185008e-01,  4.785161e-01, -8.332557e-01),        
        digits = 3, scientific = TRUE)
" 1.51e-06" " 8.49e-02" " 4.19e-01" " 4.79e-01" "-8.33e-01"
```

Comment: I'm confused because the first example is the one that says scientific = FALSE.  I think in the last example you mean TRUE.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I corrected the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you can't run the atomic vector through `format()` and get the desired result.  It has something to do with the `nsmall` argument and the number of digits to the right of the decimal (which is probably unknown) which I don't quite understand.

But it does look like we can use a list. From `help(format)`:

> If `x` is a list, the result is a character vector obtained by applying `format.default(x, ...)` to each element of the list (after `unlist`ing elements which are themselves lists), and then collapsing the result for each element with `paste(collapse = ", ")`.

So just coerce your atomic vector to a list, then it will work as desired.

```
format(as.list(x), digits=3, scientific=FALSE)
# [1] "0.00000151" "0.0849"     "0.419"      "0.479"      "-0.833"
```

Data:

```
x <- c(1.508390e-06, 8.487128e-02,  4.185008e-01,  4.785161e-01, -8.332557e-01)
```